# Does GridGain support SSL connection between each cluster member?

Tags: gridgain

Does GridGain support SSL connection between each cluster member? If yes, can you show me how to do that?

Thanks,
Bill

Comment: Generally using SSL for clustered communication will introduce significant overhead and add latencies to the network. A much better approach would be to encrypt the portions of data you need to protect on your own, before storing them in cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GridGain supports SSL only for client connections (GridGain provides .NET and C++ thin clients), but not for communication between nodes.

To enable SSL for client connections, configure your server nodes like this:

```
<bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.gridgain.grid.GridConfiguration">
    <!-- Enable REST. -->
    <property name="restEnabled" value="true"/>

    <!-- Client connection configuration. -->
    <property name="clientConnectionConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.GridClientConnectionConfiguration">
            <!-- Enable SSL. -->
            <property name="restTcpSslEnabled" value="true"/>

            <!-- Provide SSL context factory (required). -->
            <property name="restTcpSslContextFactory">
                <bean class="org.gridgain.client.ssl.GridSslBasicContextFactory">
                    <property name="keyStoreFilePath" "keystore/server.jks"/>
                    <property name="keyStorePassword" value="123456"/>
                    <property name="trustStoreFilePath" "keystore/trust.jks"/>
                    <property name="trustStorePassword" value="123456"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

You will also need to provide SSL context factory on client configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Ignite (and GridGain) allows you to use SSL for all possible connections.
To use SSL connection between nodes define property sslContextFactory in IgniteConfiguration.

```
<bean id="cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
  <property name="sslContextFactory">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.ssl.SslContextFactory">
      <property name="keyStoreFilePath" value="keystore/server.jks"/>
      <property name="keyStorePassword" value="123456"/>
      <property name="trustStoreFilePath" value="keystore/trust.jks"/>
      <property name="trustStorePassword" value="123456"/>
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>
```

You can also check official security documentation.
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/ssltls