# GridGain REST client to

Tags: rest, http, networking, gridgain

I've dug around and found the following but where not particularly useful (and why)
- [Does GridGain support SSL connection between each cluster member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772366/does-gridgain-support-ssl-connection-between-each-cluster-member/25777820#25777820) was
this wasn't so much useful as it didn't give much information on actually running and using the client
- http://atlassian.gridgain.com/wiki/display/GG60/HTTP+Client
unlike other parts of the documentation which comes with examples, the GridGain docs for HTTP REST client just shows you the fields and its properties

What I am trying to do:
I have a cluster over a virtual network running on separate virtual machines. I wish to set up a REST service so that I can hit an endpoint to store data. ie. curl POST to localhost:8080/store/ with a parameters object (or some variation of this situation, so long as I can do it over HTTP) and have that data stored into the GridGain cache

Answer (score 0):

GridGain REST protocol is MemCached compliant, so you can connect to GridGain using any MemCached compatible client.

GridGain [downloadable distribution](http://gridgain.com/download/open-source/) has PHP HTTP and MemCached examples in `examples/rest` folder.