# Opening up a GridGain node to accept put/storage requests

Tags: caching, gridgain

I am using the OSS version of GridGain so I cannot use portable objects.

I am trying to send HTTP requests containing the json serialized representation of my custom class object to be stored. I understand that because I do not portable objects this cannot be done without some middle-man work.

What I currently have set up is a jar file that takes a single line of input (the json string of the input)
1. opens a gridgain node
2. deserializes the input string to my custom class object
3. puts/loads the object into cache by conventional means in gridgain (cache.out, dataloader.addData)

This does work. But the issue is that the jar has to open a connection to a gridgain node everytime, and them closes it after the put. Opening the gridgain node and allowing it to find its peers is vastly larger than the time to load the record and isn't a viable path (imagine just sending a couple post requests at once). 
I have tried a bulk loading approach (which doesn't solve the root issue)
Ideally, I would leave a connection to a GridGain node open and thus, these put operations would occur without the overhead of closing and opening the node. 
How should I approach this?

I've already looked at the GridGain downloadable distribution's PHP HTTP and MemCached examples in examples/rest folder, as suggested in a past post: [GridGain REST client to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26267807/gridgain-rest-client-to)

I have looked into documentation for the JETTY REST HTTP client, but the lacking documentation makes it hard for me to follow. For example, here http://atlassian.gridgain.com/wiki/display/GG60/HTTP+Client it talks about the client but in version 6.x it shows that these Jetty configurations are deprecated. Furthermore, even with the JETTY client (which is used for the PHP HTTP examples mentioned above) it doesn't allow me to achieve the put/load without opening another node, I can Query the cache however.

Comment: Can you please explain why you need to start a node every time? Why is keeping node alive and just telling it to execute commands not an option?

Comment: @Dmitriy My question is asking "How would one keep the node alive and tell it to execute commands"? I cannot simply make a POST request to store data in the cache because I am using the OSS model, which I don't not believe allows me to post non-primitive objects (ie. I am storing my own custom object)

Comment: Can you start a client grid node, which will not be doing any caching, and send requests to data nodes using GridCompute API?

Comment: @Dmitriy looking at the compute examples for gridgain-fabric-os-6.5.0 I would need to start an instance of that node each time through GridGain.start("examples/config/example-compute.xml"). How would I keep this connection open meanwhile accepting compute jobs, say, through a REST API? Could you point me to an example where a client grid node is left open accepting requests for the cluster?

Comment: Can you paste a simple code example for data node startup and compute node startup the way you are using it, and I may be able to point out how to fix it. You can use [pastbin.com](http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: @Dmitriy I am starting a node using the following configuration file: http://pastebin.com/UDxLeQ7X I wish to store an instance of this object: http://pastebin.com/Rr36Ktyi. Currently, I have to open an instance of a Grid, instantiate a SimpleObject object and then using GridLoader API load the instance. (alike here: http://pastebin.com/JzRceG8f) I wish to do this via a REST HTTP request. I understand that isn't possible in the OSS model without creating the actual instance in Java and then storing it (since I can't specify the structure without the object class)